# Long-running intervals in Azure with Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm running a Node.js app in an Azure website and I'm trying to get a timer to go off every 30 seconds indefinitely. I've tried using both setInterval and [node-cron](https://npmjs.org/package/cron) but both of these stop working after about half an hour. There are no errors in the logs, and the site stays up, but the timer stops firing. I can start or recreate the timer again but it just stops working after another half an hour.

I am on the free trial period, am I running into some sort of account restriction here? Or is there some other way I should be doing this or some way to work out what is making the timer stop?

Comment: Are you using Web Sites or Cloud Services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When hosting Node.js on a website (or in fact using the node.js powershell support for Cloud Services) your node process is hosted by [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode).

IISNode will manage the lifecycle of the node process. I'm guessing it's intentionally shutting you down after 30 minutes.

You need to run node yourself in Azure if you want a process that's going to stay up. There are two options:

1. Use the Virtual Machines (currently in preview), and manually copy node.exe, and your javascript onto a virtual machine, and start your app manually (or as a scheduled task or something). You can use either Windows or Linux.
2. Use Cloud Services, and create a Worker Role which starts node as a [startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx). This gives you the ability to scale as well.