# Azure website node process lifecycle

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I 've found out that Azure websites (trial version) doesn't autostart my node sever process (it starts only when I load the url in the web browser); and that when there are no requests in a while, the process is killed.

I mean, when I git push my server, I would like it to start running immediately and continuously.

I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816113/long-running-intervals-in-azure-with-node-js), for example) that this might have to do with the way iisnode manages azure websites, and that I can't do anything to change it. Is this the actual way Azure websites work? Is there any way I can deal with this?

Thanks in advance,

Bruno.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long-running intervals in Azure with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816113/long-running-intervals-in-azure-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've find the answer. There is no other answer.

The process termination because of inactivity comes from IIS - there is [Idle Timeout setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Which to my knowledge is not configurable in Azure Web Sites (at least not Free tier). Check out also [this SO question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943111/app-pool-timeout-for-azure-web-sites) to get better understanding on why you can't change this timeout on the FREE and STANDARD tiers.

And [here is](http://ideasof.andersaberg.com/idea/14/keep-your-free-azure-website-from-idle-app-pool-timeout) an interesting workaround to avoid this idle timeout. Actually if you use technique, you will also have kind-of "auto start", in terms that when your scheduler hits your site after a new deployment, it will "boot up".

Comment: Thanks! So I'm going to have to try that workaround or move to something like a Cloud Service..

Comment: and another option for the workaround would be the new Azure Scheduler Service which could be configured to perform a GET on a url at a defined schedule.

Comment: This is the design of Windows Azure Web Sites. A little in line with Yossi's comments, if you use the Monitoring preview feature within the 'Configure' tab for a Web Site, you can have it hit your site every minute or so. This is what I do to keep my site more available and always rocking-and-rolling.

Comment: Yeah, Monitoring only works with STANDARD and RESERVED, not with FREE. while I can still use the Mobile Services approach or Scheduler with FREE. At least to the moment Scheduler is Preview, because it's free tier limits my job to 1h time interval.

Comment: I've decided to use Uptime Robot finally, that performs a get every 5 minutes.. Azure cloud services was too complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can get a little complicated, but if you don't want to use their 5-min ping service, you can keep these always on by doing the following:

1. Create an app setting on your website configuration tab within the portal:
   `WEBSITE_PRIVATE_EXTENSIONS` and give it a value of `1`
2. Create a text file named `applicationhost.xdt` and populate it with:
   `<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"><system.applicationHost><applicationPools><add name="DefaultAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.5" startMode="AlwaysRunning"><processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" /></add></applicationPools></system.applicationHost></configuration>`
3. ftp into your website and create a folder on the root directory called `Site Extensions`. (there should now be 3 folders in your root: LogFiles, site, & SiteExtensions)
4. Create another folder within 'Site Extensions', named `ASPLimits`
5. Upload the applicationhost.xdt into the ASPLimits folder
6. Restart your website using the portal